# Why Locate() in TADOTable with date/time value is not working

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-7, ado

I'm working on a small subsystem for logging user activity. The system is using MS SQL Server as a database, Delphi7 and ADO for building the interface.

The problem I have is that I can't locate a record with specific `datetime` value.

Below is a sample reproduction of the problem:

**1. Database**: MS SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.

```
-- Table creation
CREATE TABLE [tlog] (
    [USERN] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [USERDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [LOGTEXT] [varchar](250) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS NULL
);

-- Insert date/time value
INSERT INTO [tlog] (USERN, USERDATE, LOGTEXT)
VALUES (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Record current activity')
-- Insert date only value
INSERT INTO [tlog] (USERN, USERDATE, LOGTEXT)
VALUES (1, '20180202', 'Record current activity')

-- Table's content
-------------------------------------------------------------
| USERN |       USERDATE          |          LOGTEXT        |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 26/10/2015 17:13:36.597 | Record current activity |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 02/02/2018 00:00:00.000 | Record current activity |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

**2. Sample code:** Delphi 7 and ADO

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnLocateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   d: TDateTime;
   tblLog: TADOTable;
begin
   // 
   ThousandSeparator         := ' ';
   DecimalSeparator          := '.';
   DateSeparator             := '/';
   ShortDateFormat           := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
   LongDateFormat            := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
   TimeSeparator             := ':';
   ShortTimeFormat           := 'hh:mm';
   LongTimeFormat            := 'hh:mm';
   TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow := 50;
   ListSeparator             := ';';
   
   //
   tblLog := TADOTable.Create(Application);
   try
   
      //
      tblLog.ConnectionString :=
         'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;'+
         'Password=xxxx;'+
         'Persist Security Info=True;'+
         'User ID=xxxxxxxx;'+
         'Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxx;'+
         'Data Source=127.0.0.1\xxxxxxx,1066';
      tblLog.TableName := '[tlog]';
      tblLog.Open;
      
      // First try - locate with exact value. NOT WORKING.
      d := StrToDateTime('26/10/2015 17:13:36.597');
      if tblLog.Locate('USERDATE', d, []) then
         ShowMessage('Exact value, no Locate options: Located')
      else
         ShowMessage('Exact value, no Locate options: Not located');
      if tblLog.Locate('USERDATE', d, [loPartialKey]) then
         ShowMessage('Exact value, with Locate options: Located')
      else
         ShowMessage('Exact value, with Locate options: Not located');
      
      // Second try - locate with value that matches format settings. NOT WORKING.
      d := StrToDateTime('26/10/2015 17:13');
      if tblLog.Locate('USERDATE', d, []) then
         ShowMessage('Hours and minutes, no Locate options: Located')
      else
         ShowMessage('Hours and minutes, no Locate options: Not located');
      if tblLog.Locate('USERDATE', d, [loPartialKey]) then
         ShowMessage('Hours and minutes, with Locate options: Located')
      else
         ShowMessage('Hours and minutes, with Locate options: Not located');
      
      // Locate with date only value. WORKING.
      d := StrToDateTime('02/02/2018');
      if tblLog.Locate('USERDATE', d, []) then
         ShowMessage('Located')
      else
         ShowMessage('Not located');

   finally
      //
      tblLog.Close;
      tblLog.Free;
   end;   
end;
```

**3. Expected result:** Locate the record.

**4. Actual result:** `TADOTable.Locate()` returns `false`.

What am I doing wrong and how to pass `datetime` values to `TADOTable.Locate()` method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used [**Locate**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Locate) almost correctly. Almost, because the [**loPartialKey**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TLocateOptions) option you've included is pointless when searching for **TDateTime** values. In this case you need to search the exact date time value. The problem is in your tests.

Your first test has a wrong date time value. Its millisecond portion is ignored in your conversion so you're actually trying to locate date time **26/10/2015 17:13:36** which is not in your table.

In second case you're trying to locate date time **26/10/2015 17:13** which is not in your table.

I would suggest using e.g. [**EncodeDateTime**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.EncodeDateTime) function for building date time rather than that string conversion and removing those extra calls with [**loPartialKey**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TLocateOptions) option.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. In official code "loPartialKey" option is not in use. I put it in this reproduction sample just for test. I'll make some changes and I'll try EncodeDateTime function. Thanks again!

Comment: Worked fine for me in Delphi Tokyo. I just needed to fix that date time encoding thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use type string to locate or where for date with format yyyy-mm-dd

example:

in locate:

```
if tblLog.Locate('USERDATE', '2015-10-26', []) then ...
```

in where:

```
select * from tbllog where userdate = '2015-10-26'
```